# how to implement a queue of char array

Tags: c++, stl, queue

I want to use a container of the STL to use it as a buffer, so I defined something like this:

```
typedef queue<char*> CHARQUEUE;
```

then

```
CHARQUEUE p;
```

then i did some operations like:

```
p.push("mouse");
p.push("horse");
```

but what I want is a queue of char array of 256 bytes in order to hold data. Can we define something like this:

```
typedef unsigned char newtype[256]
queue<newtype> newqueue;
```

I'm using an unsigned char in order to hold some data that I don't want to change. Just to put it in the buffer and retrieve it again.

Otherwise if anyone has another implementation I'll be thankful.

Comment: Not sure why you want to do that but perhaps a `queue<string>` or a `queue<vector<char> >` would be more appropriate.

Comment: _“I'm using an unsigned char in order to hold some data that I don't want to change.”_ Did you mean `const`?

Answer (score 3):

for your queue of raw data things, just define

```
typedef unsigned char Byte;
typedef std::vector<Byte> ByteVector;
typedef std::queue< ByteVector > DataQueue;
```

for your queue of character strings, the `std::queue< std::string >` that others have suggested is fine

by the way, `ALL_UPPERCASE_NAMES` are best reserved for macros

cheers & hth.,

Comment: do I need some conversions, because of this?...char buffer[256];...DataQueue.push(buffer);

Comment: @fsidiosidi: depends. pushing copies, but, there's nothing forbidding you to read directly into a vector that is in the queue. however, *if* you have a raw array then with the typedefs above pushing would copy, it would be done like q.push( DataQueue( buffer, buffer+bufSize ) ). You'd probably want to avoid that?

Comment: yes it's all raw data coming from the socket and I guess I'll try your solution to see...thanks...I'll be in touch ...

Comment: @Steinbach: I did try the solution u give, but I get this error: error: no matching function for call to 'std::queue<char, std::deque<char, std::allocator<char> > >::queue(char [4])'|

Comment: @fsidiosidi: the error you get seem consistent with a slightly different definition, namely `std::queue< std::deque< char > >`, and that you've tried to construct such a beast with constructor argument "bah", or some other 4-element array of `char`. solution depends on what you're trying to achieve, and what your code is like. i recommend posting this as new SO question, because that allows you to post the relevant code, and because it's not really about applying my answer (different type def, different kind of operation, namely construction, not adding data). cheers,

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
std::queue<std::string>
```

EDIT:

Some alternatives.

```
std::queue<std::vector<char>>
std::queue<std::array<char, 256>>
```

Comment: In fact, the data musn't be changed...because I receive it from socket's buffer and when I'll stored in a string buffer...it will add a '\0' character ot it...I don"t want that

Answer (score 1):

Arrays don't fulfill the requirement of stdlib containers (Assignable, etc) - use e.g. boost's array type (or the one from tr1/c++1x).

Comment: There are not really arrays but pointers. And pointer should definitely fulfil the requirements.

Comment: @etarion Yes it is. And if you find a way how you can maintain it as array while passing it anywhere I will give you an upvote. Since arrays decay to pointers on any function or method call, it will be always treated as a pointer.

Comment: In fact, the data musn't be changed...because I receive it from socket's buffer and when I'll stored in a string buffer...it will add a '\0' character ot it...I don"t want that

Comment: @Let_Me_Be Also, see http://ideone.com/k8CO4 for what happens when you try the queue<newtype> thing. It doesn't work, because it is an array. Arrays and pointers are different types with different semantics. Treating them as the same doesn't work.

Comment: @etarion OK, I will give you credit, although you are not technically passing an array but a reference to a static array.

Answer (score 1):

Use `queue<string> CHARQUEUE;`

Edit:

If you want to store just pointers to some external buffers, then use `queue<const char*> CHARQUEUE;`, but note that this won't copy the data.

If you want to make copies, use `queue< vector<char> > CHARQUEUE;`.

Comment: In fact, the data musn't be changed...because I receive it from socket's buffer and when I'll stored in a string buffer...it will add a '\0' character ot it...I don"t want that

Comment: @fsidiosidi - true, but the `size()` of the `string` will not include that zero byte.  Are you trying to avoid copying the data?

Comment: not exactly...in fact I want to copy the data (raw data) from the sockets buffer to the queue...delay it for a while and take it from tha queue and copy it to the buffer of the socket...the buffer's socket is a char array..what do you think?

Comment: @fsidiosidi Use a vector of chars, or if that will be too slow, switch the vector for Boost Array http://live.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/array.html

Answer (score 0):

You could use `queue<boost::shared_array<const char>>` (see [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_array.htm)) to do this, if you want the contents to be constant.

```
queue<boost::shared_array<const char>> queueArray;
const char mouse[] = "mouse";
boost::shared_array<const char> element(mouse);
queueArray.push(element);
```